# Using cURL from inside Kubernetes Pod for API Metric Server

Tags: api, curl, kubernetes, metrics, kubernetes-apiserver

I'm having issues with curling from a Java Spring-boot application to retrieve data from the metrics API.

I'm using a custom service-account that has access to everything and the command executes properly using kube exec. In this case i'm using the token that I get from the /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token.

[kube exec -it of the curl command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9aBN.png)

Here you can see that a proper output is given but when the same curl command is called through java code this is the output.

[kubectl logs -podname-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvuIe.png)

In the next image you can see the Java code the result token here is again pulled from the directory and I can verify in the output that the command is exactly the same as the one ran during kubectl exec.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q32wC.png)

I've been banging my head against this for quite some time and I'm wondering what is going wrong.

EDIT: A way to fix this but probably not very best practice is by executing this command in your cluster kubectl create clusterrolebinding the-boss --user system:anonymous --clusterrole cluster-admin

Comment: Why are you shelling out to curl instead of using any of the dozens (probably hundreds) of Java HTTP libraries?

Comment: @coderanger mostly because I don't really know the libraries. I know how to use curl so I went for it. Do you think that would be the issue?

Comment: Most likely you've got some kind of wonky shell quoting going on and you should just go read up on literally any HTTP library rather than spending time debugging this.

Comment: Please don't post error messages nor code snippets as images; that's explicitly mentioned as a no-no in the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page